# Sprite outline and save

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, sprite, sprite-sheet

I am making a python script that can cut out sprites from a transparent background spritesheet. I want to cut out the sprites in a square or a rectangle. So far my idea is to:

**1. Get all pixel data from sheet.**

**2. Search for non-transparent pixels.**

**3. When such a pixel is found, start looking around it for other non-transparent pixels, so you can get the image correctly.**

**4. Append found pixels in a tuple, that then gets pushed into an image and saved.**

( **THE SPRITES MAY BE PLACED UNEVENLY ON THE SHEET** )

If the sprite is uneven, I will check its dimensions and then add a bit of transparent background to the sides of it, so it becomes a square or a rectangle. For example you have an image that is 53x47 I will add 19 and 25 pixels of transparent background to both sides of it so it becomes a rectangle.

I am using PIL, if there is a better way to do it, feel free to share it. If you have a better way of doing it, share as well.

This is my code so far, I can't understand how to add the transparent background on the sides and how to do the outlining correctly, also I can't seem to get the neighbourPixels function right and it makes a closed loop.

```
from PIL import Image
from sys import argv, exit

# Functions   

def neighbourPixels(pixels, row, column):
    pixel = pixels[row, column]
    data = tuple()
    holder = tuple()

    while pixel != 0:
        if pixels[row+1, column][3] != 0:
            holder = pixels[row+1, column]
            data += (holder, )
            pixel = pixels[row+1, column]
            print "In box 1"
            break
        elif pixels[row, column+1][3] != 0:
            holder = pixels[row, column+1]
            data += (holder, )
            pixel = pixels[row+1, column]
            print "In box 2"
        elif pixels[row+1, column+1][3] != 0:
            holder = pixels[row+1, column+1]
            data += (holder, )
            pixel = pixels[row+1, column]
            print "In box 3"
        elif pixels[row-1, column][3] != 0:
            holder = pixels[row-1, column]
            data += (holder, )
            pixel = pixels[row+1, column]
            print "In box 4"
        elif pixels[row, column-1][3] != 0:
            holder = pixels[row, column-1]
            data += (holder, )
            pixel = pixels[row+1, column]
            print "In box 5"
        elif pixels[row-1, column-1][3] != 0:
            holder = pixels[row-1, column-1]
            data += (holder, )
            pixel = pixels[row+1, column]
            print "In box 6"
        elif pixels[row+1, column-1][3] != 0:
            holder = pixels[row+1, column-1]
            data += (holder, )
            pixel = pixels[row+1, column]
            print "In box 7"
        elif pixels[row-1, column+1][3] != 0:
            holder = pixels[row-1, column+1]
            data += (holder, )
            pixel = pixels[row+1, column]
            print "In box 8"
        else:
            print "Sprite has been outlined."
            pixel[3] = 0

    sprite = Image.new("RGBA", (len(data), len(data)))
    sprite.putdata(data)
    return sprite


# Main
if len(argv) < 4:
    raise ValueError("Not enough arguments")

# Inicialization & Declatation
framesToCut = int(float(argv[2]))
frameSize = int(float(argv[3]))
frameToSave = Image.new("RGBA", (frameSize, frameSize))
frameCounter = 0
pixelTuple = tuple()
currentTuple = tuple()

# Preparing data
sheet = Image.open(argv[1])
width, heigth = sheet.size
pixels = sheet.load()

# Manipulation
for row in xrange(width):
    for column in xrange(heigth):
        # Searching for a pixel whos transparency is != 0
        currentPixel = pixels[row, column]
        if currentPixel[3] != 0:
            print "Pixel found!"
            print "Finding the sprite!"
            sprite = findPixels(pixels, row, column)
            if frameCounter <= framesToCut:
                # left, upper, right, lower
                frameCounter += 1
                sprite.save(str(frameCounter), "PNG")
                print "Sprite saved!"
            else:
                exit("Sprites were made O.o - Check 'em!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use scikit-image's marching squares [1]. The algorithm you are looking for is already implemented.

[1] http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_contours.html

edit: Once you have the contours using a grey-scaled image *r_grey*, just plot colored image and contours on top of each other. This example refers to the example given at the link above:

```
# Find contours at a constant value of 0.8
contours = measure.find_contours(r_grey, 0.8)

# Display the image and plot all contours found
plt.imshow(r, interpolation='nearest')

for n, contour in enumerate(contours):
    plt.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2)
```

The original code told you to use *r* (the image) and plot it. This is what we continue to do. Remember: grey-scaled and colored image have the same coordinates.

Comment: I don't think the sprites have a constant value outlining. The algorithm looks like the thing I need, but can you tell me if it will work for a spritesheet kinda like this one here -> [This](http://www.spriters-resource.com/resources/sheets/39/42176.png) The background is transparent.

Comment: Sure, it'll work. I suggest that you create a copy of the image just for contour detection. The copy will contain only black/white information (binary). Depending on which colors and transparencies should be included in the image, you turn areas into black within this image. This procedure will give you freedom to choose the desired areas.

Comment: Hmm, can you give me a sample code as to how to use the algorith itself? I understand how to make the sheet greyscale, then put it in a numpy array, but then I don't know how to use the algorithm and put each result in a colored image file.

Comment: Yup, please check out my edited answer. It refers to the code example that is given at [1].